# Why is my iCloud KVS Observer not working

Tags: swift, icloud, key-value-observing, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

In my app I implemented a `Preferences` class that looks like this.

```
public class Preferences: Codable {
    public static var sharedPreferences: Preferences = {
        let preferences = Preferences()

        return preferences
    }()

    public class func shared() -> Preferences {
        return sharedPreferences
    }

    private let cloud: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default

    public init () {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keysDidChangeOnCloud(notification:)),
                                               name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification,
                                               object: nil)
        self.cloud.synchronize()
    }

    @objc func keysDidChangeOnCloud(notification: Notification) {
        print("CLOUD CHANGED")
    }
}
```

I observe a change in the Key Value storage. That `print()` is never executed though. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe not relevant but if `Preferences` is supposed to be a singleton then the `init()` method should be private.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to observe the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default object like so:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keysDidChangeOnCloud(notification:)),
                                           name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification,
                                           object: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default)
```

Comment: Hi - I have the exact code, but it does not work for me. I never get the notification, when I change any KVs...any other way to debug this